# Comparing Table 1 with Table 2 in Netezza where Table 1 has million records

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, nzplsql

I'm new to SQL and trying the examples but didn't find it as per my requirement. I would be happy if any pro can able to answer.

I have a Table A with 150 columns and millions of records. I need to compare the Table A with Table B(Both Table A and B is in Netteza).

I need a SQL query which can compare the both tables A and B record by record and give me results if there is discrepancy in the record of Table B.

### Table A

```
FirstName LastName ZipCode
Gary      Martin   500020
John      Mills    788802
```

### Table B

```
FirstName LastName ZipCode
Gary      Martin   500020
John      Mill     788802
```

Expected to get results like this:

```
FirstName LastName ZipCode   FirstName LastName ZipCode 
John      Mills    788802    John      Mill     788802
```

Comment: what about the other records Gary and Martin

Comment: since no discrepancy in table B for the Gary Martin records no need to show in results.

Comment: 150 columns? go punch on the nose the guy who built that. >.< Your query needs to compare field by field, all 150 of them  e.g. WHERE a.FirstName != b.FirstName OR a.LastName != a.LastName OR [etc...]

Comment: Select * from Table A AND Table B

Comment: Select * from Table A AND Table B WHERE a.FirstName != b.FirstName OR a.LastName != b.LastName OR [etc]... is that right ? Ricardo!......sure I'm going to punch when it's time.

Answer (score 1):

Are the table structures exactly the same?  If so you could potentially use Set Operators, though the performance might not be the best.  Something along the lines of:

```
Select * 
  from (Select * From TableA
       MINUS
       Select * from TableB) A
       Join
       (select * from TableB
       MINUS
       Select * from TableA) ON *common unique field if there is one*
```

Each of the MINUS sub queries will give you the records in the First table which an exact match can't be found for in the second.  If there's a common unique identifier in the two tables then you could then join the results of the two sub-queries to get the result you're expecting.